# Can we save Gnome Terminal Window with multiple tabs with logins?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

Every time i would be required to launch a new terminal window as a refresh start and then do logins, i would like to reduce this effort across reboots, any idea ? Something similar to Mputty Thanks.